# How can I use the LoadString macros in my namespace?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, namespaces, macros

I have a problem with the `LoadString` WinAPI macros when I use it in my namespace. My function:

```
namespace Bushman {
    // Get the string from the resource's string table of the module.
    // I use the same name like WinAPI macros but with own signature.
    PTSTR LoadString(HMODULE h, DWORD id) {
        h = NULL == h ? ::GetModuleHandle(NULL) : h;
        PTSTR ptr = NULL;
        // it returns really length instead of concatenated 
        // string length, therefore I can use it for malloc.
        int i = ::LoadString(h, id, (PTSTR)&ptr, 0);
        if (0 == i) {
            return NULL;
        }
        PTSTR string = (PTSTR)malloc(i * (sizeof(TCHAR) + 1));
        ::LoadString(h, id, string, i + 1);
        return string; // NOTE: don't forget free resource in the outer code.
    }
}
```

I get the compilation error:

> 'LoadStringW': is not a member of 'Bushman'
>  'LoadStringW': is not
>   a member of 'Bushman'
>  'LoadStringW': is not a member of
>   'Bushman'

How can I fix it?

**UPD**

I think the problem is the macros has such definition

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define LoadString  LoadStringW
#else
#define LoadString  LoadStringA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

instead of something like this:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define LoadString  ::LoadStringW
#else
#define LoadString  ::LoadStringA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

**UPD 2**

I found the reason of my problem. The problem was in other place of my code. I used such declarations in my code:

```
namespace Bushman {} // namespace declaration
PTSTR Bushman::LoadString(HMODULE h, DWORD id); // function declaration
```

but it is wrong. All works fine if I rewrite it to this:

```
namespace Bushman {
    PTSTR LoadString(HMODULE h, DWORD id);
}
```

Comment: So the error message was accurate, the extra W was just a false lead.  That happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few of options:

1. Don't include the Windows header file that defines the `LoadString` macro, or
2. Include that header file, but undefine the macro with `#undef`.

There's really no nice solution to this problem. As soon as you start to use macros then you lose the ability to readily isolate and control their influence. The preprocessor does not care about your namespaces.

---

Regarding your updates to the question, you have not really solved the problem. As of the code in your UPD2, the preprocessor converts `LoadString` to `LoadStringW`. You just don't realise that because it happens transparently during compilation. But if you try to use your class from another translation unit which does not define the `LoadString` macro you will find that the function is named `LoadStringW`.

Comment: Thank you. I added **UPD** in my theme.

Comment: I don't think that changes anything I said. You included a unit which defines a truck load of macros. And these are the consequences.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Would "3. Change the name of the custom `LoadString` method so it doesn't collide with the original its replacing." also be a good option to recommend?

Comment: @theB Maybe. It's a big limiting though. I'd prefer to isolate the user of the windows header files to low level code that wraps up any functionality. Fundamentally though the Windows header files reliance on macros leaves no good solutions.

Comment: David, I added the **UPD 2**. :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess your function is now named `LoadStringW` which I doubt you really want. Why are you including a macro to redefine `LoadString`?

Comment: I agree with you there as far as the macros are concerned. I tend to avoid using the same name regardless, because at a glance its often hard to tell from calling code that you're calling a replacement.  (Of course that specific reason doesn't apply here.) [See also](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/06/17/10622037.aspx)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, my function is named `LoadString` still. I use in my code the `LoadString` macros instead of `LoadStringW` because the same does the author of the book (Windows via C\C++) which I am reading. I think this way can be useful if the `wchar_t` will be replased by something more capacious in future.

Comment: You might think that the function is named `LoadString`, and it appears that way in your source code, but don't the preprocessor macros change that?

Comment: How can that be? Surely the preprocessor replaces all instance of `LoadString` with `LoadStringW`. Isn't that what a preprocessor does?

Comment: In other words, you might think that the name is `LoadString`, because that's what you see in your source code. But the preprocessor has changed all the occurrences of `LoadString` to `LoadStringW`, and that's what the compiler sees. Remember that the compiler doesn't see your source code. The preprocessor does. The compiler sees whatever the preprocessor emits.

Comment: This is correct.  ALL occurrences of `LoadString` will be replaced with `LoadStringW` during preprocessing prior to compiling. The rule of thumb is DON'T give your custom functions the same names as Win32 API functions (because Microsoft uses macros, which don't respect namespace/class hierarchies), then you won't run into this issue.